# how to take data from data base and show the uipickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uipickerview

I am fetching the data from `sqlite3`, now i need to display that values in `UIPicker` view , Can any one help me please,

I got the response from data base like

```
stateName: (
        {
        "state_name" = Alabama;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Arizona;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Arkansas;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = California;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Colorado;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Connecticut;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Delaware;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "District of Columbia";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Florida;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Georgia;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Idaho;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Illinois;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Indiana;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Iowa;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Kansas;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Kentucky;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Louisiana;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Maine;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Maryland;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Massachusetts;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Michigan;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Minnesota;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Mississippi;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Missouri;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Montana;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Nebraska;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Nevada;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "New Hampshire";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "New Jersey";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "New Mexico";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "New York";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "North Carolina";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "North Dakota";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Ohio;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Oklahoma;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Oregon;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Pennsylvania;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "Rhode Island";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "South Carolina";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "South Dakota";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Tennessee;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Texas;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Utah;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Vermont;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Virginia;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Washington;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = "West Virginia";
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Wisconsin;
    },
        {
        "state_name" = Wyoming;
    }
)
```

Comment: Why some state_name are Strings and the other not?

Comment: @EnriMR: They may be NSStrings, that's just that since they are in "one word", it doesn't always show the quotes.

Comment: can you put some code that you tried..?

Comment: Other one also string but it contains two or three words, so its showing "" quatation Bro

Comment: -(NSMutableArray *) displayState
{
    NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *query = @"SELECT state_name FROM states";


    NSArray *result = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[DBManager sharedInstance] loadDataFromDB:query]];
    NSLog(@"stateName: %@",result);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < [result count]; i++)
    {
        States *state = [[States alloc] loadFromDictionary:[result objectAtIndex:i]];
        [list addObject:state];
        
    }
    
    return list;
}

Comment: have look at [ActionSheetStringPicker](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) this will also have example for how to use it

Comment: i gone through that code Those Values are hardcoded, but i here i need to display from data base as key value for @"state_name".

Answer (score 0):

There is the delegate method of UIPickerView.  #pragma mark - PickerView Delegates

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

//=====================================================================================
//Customize Number of rows in Component
//=====================================================================================
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if([genreList count] != 0)
    {
        return [genreList count];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


//=====================================================================================
//Set title For Row
//=====================================================================================
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row1 forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if([genreList count] != 0)
    {
        return [genreList objectAtIndex:row1];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }


    //return 4;

}
```